# How do I check nested If statements in JavaScipt

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, so I'm currently working on a script that is supposed to update a string called `Wasl_Status`. These are the for conditions I'm trying to check:

Here is my code so far:

```
if (analog2 == 0) {
  return "Tamper Weight";
}
if ((analog1 == 0) && (speed == 0)) {
  return "Parked Device Disconnected";
}
if ((analog1 == 0) && (speed > 0)) {
  return "Moving Device Disconnected";
if ((ignition == true) && (speed == 0))
    return 'Parked Engine On';
if ((ignition == false) && (speed == 0))
    return 'Parked Engine Off';
if (speed > 0)
    return "Moving";
}
```

When I test it, the Wasl_Status only outputs the first three conditions and it ignores all the last three conditions. How do I make it to check every condition and return all 6 values? What I read so far is to create an array but current instructions say I must do nested if statements. I hope my question is clear. Thank you.

Comment: you shouldn't do if else this way. you should take else literally for everything what wasn't catched by your ifs ifelses

Comment: do you want  the code inside the else to occur if `analog2 == 0`?

Comment: Your `else` is paired with `if ((analog1 == 0) && (speed > 0)){
  return "Moving Device Disconnected";
}`, do you know that?

Comment: and this code: `if ((analog1 == 0) && (speed == 0)){
    return "Parked Device Disconnected";
}
if ((analog1 == 0) && (speed > 0)){
  return "Moving Device Disconnected";
}`
 is never going to occur since you already returned something

Comment: Edit: Else is now deleted.

Comment: do you know `else if `? it is either ... or then it will not check every condition once. It will check if one condition matches and will not check the other ones

Answer (score 0):

While it's correct, what you're doing, I think it's easier to read and follow the code if you, in most cases, try to `return` the value at the end of the function:

```
var message = 'no statements fit';

if      (analog2 == 0)                      { message = "Tamper Weight"; }
else if (analog1 == 0        && speed == 0) { message = "Parked Device Disconnected"; }
else if (analog1 == 0        && speed > 0)  {
  message = "Moving Device Disconnected";
   
  if      (ignition == true  && speed == 0) { message = 'Parked Engine On'; }
  else if (ignition == false && speed == 0) { message = 'Parked Engine Off'; }
  else if (speed > 0)                       { message = "Moving"; }
}

return message;
```

Then you would see, in an easier way, what is returning and when:

```
if ((analog1 == 0) && (speed > 0)) {
  return "Moving Device Disconnected";
  // ... everything after this code will never be executed because the function "stops" executing after a return.
```